# Space covering text on select element

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to remove this white space that covers the value in my dropdown menu? I have attached photos, cheers.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqWg0.png

```css
.radiusdrop {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 55px;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<select class="radiusdrop" name="radius" id="">
  <option value="2">2km</option>
  <option value="2">5km</option>
  <option value="2">10km</option>
  <option value="2">20km</option>
  <option value="2">50km</option>
  <option value="2">100km</option>
  <option value="2">250km</option>
  <option value="2">500km</option>

</select>
```

Comment: can you add the html code for your dropdown...

Comment: @Gelxxxx Sorry, just did

Comment: set padding to `padding: 0 0px 0 20px;`

Comment: @Gelxxxx im an idiot thank you